# Is 'change' event in Backbone.js only "reference based" change instead of "value based" change

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I write one piece of test code:

```
var ModelHasObjectAttribute = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
        property_value:99   ,
        object_attr:{"year":"1990"}
    },
    setYear:function(year) {  // function like this cannot trigger change
        var temp_object_attr = jQuery.extend({},  this.get('object_attr')  ); // This shallow copy is to change the reference of object_attr,
        temp_object_attr["year"] = year;            // otherwise I cannot trigger 'change' event, if the value of one attribute changed but reference not changed                   
        this.set( 'object_attr', temp_object_attr );    
    },
    changeYear:function( year ) {
        console.log("before changing, " + this.get('object_attr')['year']);
        this.get('object_attr')["year"] = year;
        console.log( this.get('object_attr'));  
    },
    initialize: function () {
        var classRef = this;
        this.on('change:property_value', function() {
            alert("heard property_value changing");
        });
        this.on('change:maxvalue', function() {
            alert("heard maxvalue changing");   
        }); 
        this.on('change:object_attr', function() {
            alert('heard object_attr changing' + classRef.get('object_attr')['year']);  
        });
    }   
});
var on_instance = new ModelHasObjectAttribute ();
on_instance.set('property_value',10);
on_instance.changeYear(2015); // this line of code does not trigger default 'change' event 
on_instance.setYear(2016);    // this one triggered 
console.log( on_instance.get('object_attr') );
```

For example, if I want `change` to be triggered when `object_attr` is changed,
I have to change the reference of the object stored under `object_attr`.
just modify the value of object of `object_attr`, will not trigger `change`.

How can I avoid the expensive shallow copy, and also trigger change events?

Answer (score 1):

That approach doesn't work because Backbone has no way to detect that you have changed the `object_attr` object. This isn't so much a Backbone issue as a general JavaScript point - you can't observe object property changes ([yet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe)).

The best way to set deep attributes with change events is to use a plugin like [Backbone.DeepModel](https://github.com/kahwee/backbone-deep-model), which overrides `set` to work with nested attributes:

```
var ModelHasObjectAttribute = Backbone.Model.extend({
  // ...  
  setYear:function(year) { 
    // triggers 'change' events
    this.set('object_attr.year', year); 
  },
  // ...
}
```

N.B. The link is to a recent fork of DeepModel. Depending on your app setup, you may need to use the [(unmaintained) original version](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-deep-model).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think it is a good one, I also used one workaround, that is  make object_attr one Backbone model